# CPU Starvation detected because of MQ exception

Tags: ibm-mq

> **0002bc2d SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: JMSCC3036: An exception has been delivered to the
>   connections exception listener: '
>                          Message : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has o
>   ccurred. An error has occurred with the WebSphere MQ JMS connection. Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this e
>   rror.
>                            Class : class com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException
>                            Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:608)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:236)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.consumer(WMQConnection.java:851)
>                                  : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteAsyncConsume.callEventHandler(RemoteAsyncConsume.java:1
>   023)
>                                  : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteAsyncConsume.driveEventsEH(RemoteAsyncConsume.java:1381
>   )
>                                  : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:310)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:209)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.j
>   ava:100)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:224)
>                                  : com.ibm.ws.wmqcsi.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImpl$WorkQueueRunnable.run(WorkQueueManagerImpl.j
>   ava:648)
>                                  : java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
>        Caused by [1] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED'
>   ) reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
>                            Class : class com.ibm.mq.MQException
>                            Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:223)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.consumer(WMQConnection.java:851)
>                                  : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteAsyncConsume.callEventHandler(RemoteAsyncConsume.java:1
>   023)
>                                  : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteAsyncConsume.driveEventsEH(RemoteAsyncConsume.java:1381)
>                                  : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:310)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:209)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.j
>   ava:100)
>                                  : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:224)
>                                  : com.ibm.ws.wmqcsi.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImpl$WorkQueueRunnable.run(WorkQueueManagerImpl.j
>   ava:648)
>                                  : java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
>   '.

Please can anybody explain what this exception means and why has this caused CPU starvation**

Answer (score 3):

Did you review your own logfile?

> JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred. An error has
>   occurred with the WebSphere MQ JMS connection. Use the linked
>   exception to determine the cause of this error.

And further down it says:

> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738) Caused by [1] --> Message : 
>   com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with
>   compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED' ) reason '2009'
>   ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').

Did you look up MQ reason code 2009 in the MQ Information Center?  Basically, it means the connection to the queue manager was lost and you need to reconnect.

> and why has this caused CPU starvation

Any CPU starvation you are seeing has nothing to do with error but rather your code is not properly handling the error and is probably in a loop racing around and around in circles doing nothing.